# mapStateToProps not accessing nested object correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

***EDIT:*** I fixed the images to make them more easily veiwable

I don't understand what's going on with the `mapStateToProps()` here. The  `console.log()` prints out what you see in the image, so it accesses `state` and `state.image.urls` after the async call. Also, in the render method it reads `this.props.image` fine with the error message you see, noting that it sees a key of 'raw' there, but for some reason once I do `state.image.urls.raw` or `this.props.image.raw`, it says it can't find 'raw' of undefined, even though it shows it in the console. I tried `['raw']` as well, but neither work. It doesn't work for the state values commented out either. Why is this happening?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getBackgroundImage();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        {console.log(this.props.image)}                   (LINE 15)
        <Container
          photoProfile={this.props.photographerProfile}
          photoName={this.props.photographerName}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);                                      (LINE 26)
  console.log(state.image.urls);                           (LINE 27)
  return {
    image: state.image.urls
    // photographerProfile: state.image.user.links.html,
    // photographerName: state.image.user.name
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getBackgroundImage }
)(App);
```

[image: console image 1]
[image: console image 2]

Comment: Is it just complaining about the console.log on line 15?

Comment: If you are referring to the error "Objects are not valid as a React child" it is not a problem of "mapStateToProps". It is a problem that somewhere in a render method, you are trying to render and object. React can't do that. Can you show how the "Container" component looks like?

Comment: If i take that console.log out(of this.props.image), and add '.raw' to the state in mapStateToProps, it throws an error saying it can't find 'raw' of undefined, but the console.log of the state inside mapStateToProps is showing the key of raw.

Comment: Are you fetching the "urls" asynchronously? If so, it is "undefined" at first time it tries to grab it. Try lodash `_.get(state, 'image.urls.raw', ""})`.

Comment: But where I'm confused is that, even after the async call, it updates the state, as can be seen in the console, so it reads `state.image.urls` without throwing an error. The error only occurs once I add `.raw` or `.full` to the end of it.

Comment: You probably have an "initial" state right? And you have the "image" key there somewhere (probably as empty object?). JavaScript is okay with accessing properties of an empty object. But it can not access properties of "undefiend". Which "urls" is at the time of accessing "state.image.urls.raw". Makes sense?

Comment: So you're saying it will access `.urls` of an empty object(`state.image`) and not throw an error, but when it tries to access `.raw` of `.urls` which would be undefined, it throws the error?

Comment: Yes. `const a = {}` then `a.user => "undefined"`.

But. `a.user.data => "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"`

Comment: Well, this would all make sense then. Thanks for the help!